# table cell for message from social network; iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uikit

Please, say how create this type table cell? For message from social network

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Bubble Chat there are so many open sources UI which uses so many different approaches, so you will have no problem with that. In fact you need to customize manually

Open Source :

[BubbleThingie for iOS](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/bubblethingie)

[PTSMessagingCell for iOS](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/ptsmessagingcell)

[UIBubbleTableView](http://alexbarinov.github.io/UIBubbleTableView/)

Paid One :

[STBubbleTableViewCell for iOS](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/stbubbletableviewcell)

Hope, this helps you !